# What is a good way to determine via server object model if a field supports multiple values?

Tags: spfield, multiple-values

When looking at an SPField object, how can I tell if it supports multiple values?

I.e. a Choice field that is displayed using Checkboxes, a Managed Metadata field that allows multiple values, Person or Group that allows multiple selections, and quite possibly something I'm not thinking of?

The best I've come up with is compiling a list of multi valued types (e.g. TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti, LookupMulti, UserMulti..) and comparing against FieldTypeAsString. I'm wondering if there's a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookup fields (which [user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduser.aspx) extends) supports [AllowMultipleValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookup.allowmultiplevalues.aspx).

Then you can do:

```
var multi = field is SPFieldMultiChoice || 
    (field is SPFieldLookup && (field as SPFieldLookup).AllowMultipleValues);
```

Same for [Taxonomy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfield.allowmultiplevalues.aspx)

Comment: I think this will work for me. I don't necessarily care about supporting arbitrary custom field types, but this would also work if they inherit from something sensible. To support multi choice columns as well: `field is SPFieldMultiChoice || (field is SPFieldLookup && (field as SPFieldLookup).AllowMultipleValues)`

Comment: I updated the answer :)  And yes you would have to implement all kind of checks if you want to 'cover it all' as far as I know :(